# ASP.NET 5 IIS on windows 10 HttpPlatformHandler Getting 404 Not found

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, windows-10, dnx

I have followed the documentation on the [ASP.NET site](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) to deploy an ASP.NET5 website on IIS, When I browse the site at http://localhost/mysite I get a 404 Not found:

> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Server: Kestrel
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2016 18:15:57 GMT

(from fiddler)

if I check Application Event logs I find an entry against HttpPlatformHandler:

> The description for Event ID 1001 from source HttpPlatformHandler cannot be  found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>   If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>   The following information was included with the event:
>   Process '3896' started successfully and is listening on port '6277'.

If I browse http://localhost:6277  I find that the website is running fine.

So my guess is that the HttpPLatformHandler is not proxying the site correctly??

I am using DNX version 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Has anyone had this issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: So, when trying to browse to the site, are you going through the link on the Site in IIS? Mostly it seems to me that you're not actually going through IIS.

Comment: I am hitting the site via IIS, that's what returns the 404  from http://localhost/mysite

Comment: I had a similar issue that ended up being permissions related which may not be the case here.  Curious, is there anything in the Log directory on the web-site that's useful?

Comment: @b.pell What permissions, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I have my notes at work (and will double check with our sysadmin) tomorrow morning and post back.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer in another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897100/asp-net-5-add-app-as-iis-application)

It seems there is a bug with RC1 and the HttpPlatformHandler.  See [ASP.NET IIS Integration issue #14](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14).

The issue is related to case when hosting our app in a sub-site in IIS meaning we have to tell ASP the path:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Map("/mysite", (myAppSite) => this.ConfigureMyAppPath(myAppSite, env));
}

public void ConfigureMyAppPath(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // the actual Configure code
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You saved me tons of time and headache. Hope this gets fixed soon.