# Routing issues with MVC 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Server is 2008 R2. I am getting 404 back.

I have confirmed that Configure and ConfigureServices in Startup.cs completed without error by placing this code at the end

```
 app.Run(async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from RC1!");
        });
```

However, requests don't get to my controller when I navigate to it . I believe it might be a routing problem. Log files pointed to by stdoutLogFile don't show any errors.

I can RDP in and browse to the site after running web.cmd in the approot directory. Site runs fine that way. Can not access it with IIS.

Update

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {         
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseSession();       
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            app.UseMvc(RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes);
        });          

    }


public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(IRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full `Configure` method in Startup.cs?

Comment: [This post solved my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184997/asp-net-5-iis-on-windows-10-httpplatformhandler-getting-404-not-found). Hopefully this will help someone else too.